# Что это за поле: input type="hidden"?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Помогите разобраться в коде. Начала изучать php по урокам Попова, все понятно, но в HTML коде сайта-примера непонятен вот этот кусок:

```
<div class="formm" width:"80%">
<p class="form3">Подписывайтесь на нашу рассылку и получайте свежие уроки, статьи и новости, прямо в свой почтовый ящик!</p>
<form action="" method="post" name="SR_form" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name = "version" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name = "tid" value="34769">
<input type="hidden" name = "uid" value="27025">
<input type="hidden" name = "charset" value="windows-1251">
<input type="hidden" name = "lang" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name = "did[]" value="9267">
<p class="form1">Имя на русском:</p>
<input type = "text" name = "field_email" size = "20" value = "" maxlength = "50" style: border = "1px" #C5C5C5>
 <p class="form1">Email адрес:</p>
 <input type = "text" name = "field_email" size = "20" value = "" maxlength = "50" style: margin = "0px"; padding = "0px">
 <p "style = margin:5px; margin-top:"10px"; padding:0px;">
 <input type = "submit" name"SR_submitButton" value = "Подписаться" style = "font-family:Verdana, sans-serif" >
 </p>
</form>
</div>
```

А именно:

```
<input type="hidden" name = "version" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name = "tid" value="34769">
<input type="hidden" name = "uid" value="27025">
<input type="hidden" name = "charset" value="windows-1251">
<input type="hidden" name = "lang" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name = "did[]" value="9267">
```

Это какое-то невидимое поле? Для чего оно?

И в CSS коде несовсем понятен вот этот момент:

```
html>body #coolmenu a{ 
    width: auto;
}
```

наверное, это означает "в тегах боди"? Спасибо.

Comment: кнопка 101010 потом поговорим

Comment: непонятно... что, глупый вопрос? извините, но я пока еще совсем чайник...

Comment: ничего, может научится и варить когда нибудь :-)

Comment: надеюсь)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Описание input type](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/type)

К описанию добавлю что эти поля используются для: проверки, отправки или хранения каких либо нужных вам данных которые вы будите извлекать или записывать с помощью того же PHP в эти поля

html>body хак для бараньих браузеров типа IE

Comment: Теперь все понятно, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

это скрытые поля, в которые можно подставить данные при помощи php или js незаметно для пользователя. а потом получить их в обработчик с остальными полями формы, получить можно через $_POST или $_GET в зависимости от того что вы указали в теге <form... .
а вообще прежде чем за пхп браться, изучите хотя бы хтмл

Comment: а кто говорит, что не изучала? просто такого не встречала еще, эти поля ведь с PHP связаны.

Comment: а причем тут пхп? это не только на пхп расчитано, это могут многие зыки принимать, пхп просто самый популярный из них, а хтмл полезно изучить, тк <input это чистый хтмл и css пригодится тоже, а про js вообще молчу )) небойтесь со временем научитесь и поймете все!

Comment: и js и html изучала. давненько правда. очень надеюсь что всему научусь!

Comment: и еще хотела поблагодарить за развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать например при редактировании записи - оставлять её id в спрятанном поле hidden. Пользователь его не увидит, а данные вы получите в post-запросе.

Будьте аккуратны, так как злые люди могут туда подставить что угодно.

Comment: спасибо, пригодится!